# onResume like overide in a fragment

Tags: android

**The Scene**

I have an activity that houses 2 fragments .

1. Activity A is launched.
2. Fragment B completely takes over the activity A (UI wise).
   Here depending on the operation , Fragment C launches and takes over the whole UI

**The Target**

I want to be able to know when a user presses back from Fragment C , and lands back on fragment B .

**The Problem**.

We all know that we CANNOT use the onResume override in the Fragment B  , because this onResume is closely coupled with the Activity's lifecycle. If there was an override like onResume in Fragment B , it would have really helped my case. I know that the Fragment B is not onPaused when Fragment C overtakes it , so I am aware that onResume like strategy wont work .

**The Solution**

I think I can attach a callback onBackPressed in Activity A . Something like .

Psuedo Code

```
 private onBackPressed()
 {
    if (currentFragment == Fragment C) {
       FragmentB = findFragmentB();
       //call custom method written in FragmentB
       FragmentB.onBackPressed();
    } else {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }
```

Before I proceeded , is this the right direction to move in ?

Comment: You CAN use the fragments onResume() and you SHOULD. The activities onResume() calls the fragments onResume(). This is a good thing.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't work . I press back from Fragment C , and Fragment B's onResume doesn't work . :( .

Comment: Yes, In terms of psuedo code, you are thinking right. Just check this with the instances. Like
if (currentFragment instance of Fragment C)
    {
}

Answer (score 0):

Exactly,,, if there is most suitable and easy solution for this problem. i think you should continue with this. I find out other ways but this was better and easy then others

Answer (score -1):

Something alone the lines of this should work

```
BaseFragment currFrag = (BaseFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentname);
currFrag.onFragmentResume();
```

Not much to explain here, onFragmentResume literally calls onResume of the fragment.

Comment: I don't think you should be calling the lifecycle methods of a fragment or activity manually....

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't think he refers to call a lifecycle method, because it does not exist such method. It seems that what he says is that you should create a BaseFragment class with that method.